# Why does switching to the MEMORY engine increases the table size?

Tags: mysql, memory

Why does changing the engine from MyISAM to MEMORY increase the table size so much? 
I'm trying to change a table that contains 13 millions records to MEMORY and I have 6GB Memory, and in Myisam the size is 1.5GB and i want to be around this size using the MEMORY engine so it fits my memory limit.

I also defined this

```
{tmp_table_size=5.5G
max_heap_table_size=5.5G}
```

and I still get a **"table is full"** error, so my only guess is that when converting to MEMORY engine the table size needs to be around 10-15GB.

Thank you

Comment: What's structure of that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MEMORY (or HEAP) table engine supports only the fixed-row format.

As a result a `VARCHAR(255)` column is stored like a `CHAR(255)`: it consumes 255 bytes in each row, even if it contains only 10 characters, plus a few bytes for meta data (e.g. for storing the length). If the column is in UTF-8, it consumes 3 bytes per character, i.e. 3*255 per row, plus meta data.

See *Physical Characteristics of MEMORY Tables* at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html :

> MEMORY tables use a fixed-length row-storage format. Variable-length types such as VARCHAR are stored using a fixed length.